# How to Extract a Common Hypernym from Different Words Using WordNet (Java)?

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet, jwi

Does anyone know how to find a common Hypernym given two words, using WordNet in Java?

For example the hypernym for chicken is bird, and the hypernym for parrot is also bird. So if one provides

```
 hypernym_finder ("parrot", "chicken")
```

the result should be "bird".

(I made a more specific question in another post, with codes and details - maybe a more general one would attract more people)

Answer (score 0):

this library can give you the answer, e.g, fast start logic outlined here:
https://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/calculate-words-similarity-using-wordnet-in-java/

(metric=edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.WuPalmer@79efed2d) :: (chicken,parrot) = 0.72

Comment: Thanks ! I forgot to get back here.
I started using  really good API
https://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/